# Paraller task schedulling in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduling

Hi I have a question about task schedulling. I have several controllers, and I want to make calls to that controllers using Laravel task scheduling.I have add one line of cronjob into the server. I have a code like this in kernel.php file, which one basically works.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\firstController@index')->everyMinute()->name('firstController_cronjob')->withoutOverlapping(); 
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\secondController@index')->everyMinute()->name('secondController_cronjob')->withoutOverlapping();
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\thirdController@index')->everyMinute()->name('thirdController_cronjob')->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

But I have one issue. This script run sequentially. Is it possible to run Laravel controllers as parallel scheduled task?

Comment: doesn't that have something to do with `ShouldQueue`?

Comment: I'm new in this. Can you explain or provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `runInBackground()` not mentioned in Laravel docs but listed in [their API](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_runInBackground).

You can add it to each `$schedule` line:

```
$schedule->...->runInBackground();
```

and see if it helps. I'm not sure if it will work with `withoutOverlapping()`, though. I did little test on Laravel 5.2 with PHP 7 and IIS and none of tasks have logged anything, despite having some `Log::info()` inside. It also happily let me execute multiple `artisan schedule:run` commands without checking if task was finished.

---

Other possibility (for `artisan` commands) could be to use Symfony's [Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) class directly to start background processes:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

[...]

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {

    $schedule->call(function() { 
        return (new Process('php artisan test:test'))->start(); 
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

In this case the script won't check for overlapped tasks and adding `withoutOverlapping()` may not suffice - you would rather need to write your own methods for adding/removing mutex and run them in the e.g. task itself.